# 5n + 8n^2 + 100n^3 = O(n^2 log2 (n)) true or false statement?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

5n + 8n^2 + 100n^3 = O(n^2 log2 (n)) true or false statement ?

My answer : **(PLEASE CORRECT ME IF I'M WRONG, I AM STILL A BEGINNER AT THIS COURSE)**
well first i was looking for what is "O" in this exercice ? 
does it mean log base 2?

if O equals (5n + 8n^2 + 100n^3) / (n^2 log2 (n)) 
then this is true 
that simplifies to 
O = ((5/n) + 8 + 100n) / log₂n

Comment: This is big-$O$ notation.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

Comment: Okay i understood that O means the big-O , so is my answer right ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you find a constant $C$ so that $n^3\le Cn^2\log_2{n}$?